# Is there a mature, easy-to-use CQRS framework that is not Azure-specific, not outdated, or not well adopted?

Tags: .net, cqrs

I've been doing research on .net implementations with CQRS. Either everything I've seen so far is do-it-yourself, azure-specific, outdated (i think), or not well adopted

Problems:

- Scritchy - is not well adopted
- NCQRS - appears to be a bit older? it also requires a DIY-ish setup - meaning, you need to create several projects yourself (not all that terrible though).
- https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r - more of a theoretical demo than a production framework
- LOKAD.CQRS - mostly azure specific
- https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin - again, more of a demo than framework

I'm working on a new project. It will be hosted in AppHarbor. I would like to use a CQRS approach. I would prefer to use an awesome framework rather than write/copy it myself.

Comment: voted to move to SO since it's a technology specific question, good luck  :-)

Comment: @DKnight thanks but no thanks. This is a conceptual software development question. There is no specific programming issue to be solved. There is no source code to be attributed to this question.

Comment: any feedback on which framework you chose?

Answer (score 8):

(Disclaimer: I am the author of Scritchy)

I can not talk for the other frameworks, but in my case, Scritchy merely exists because I wanted to provide a quick and easy to use tool for writing CQRS apps, also taking away some of the burden of writing similar command handlers over and over...

As the experts are saying: CQRS in it's most basic representation is quite simple, so it does not really require a framework.

However, since I personally use the CQRS approach a lot and I hated writing the same boilerplate code over and over, I decided to write an opinionated framework for it (think RoR for CQRS).

Scritchy is a very pragmatic and opinionated approach to CQRS (preferring convention over configuration), but it has been designed in a way that every component should easily be replaceable by some other component... (i.e. an easy to replace base class for your ARs is the only dependency).

As Scritchy has been in development for only a short time - even though it functions perfectly for my needs -, it is not as adopted as most of the other frameworks.

One framework a lot of the people in the community seem to approve, is [Jonathan Oliver's event store](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore), which is not a specific CQRS framework per sé, but he does offer [some CommonDomain objects you can use](https://github.com/joliver/CommonDomain) in your CQRS apps.

My suggestion: pick one, setup basic infrastructure and get started. The hardest part in CQRS is usually not in the infrastructure, but in the domain (or at least, it should be ;) )